# ktrain ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, dll

I'm using windows 10

- python version: 3.7.1
- ktrain version: 0.11.3
- tensorflow downgrade to 2.0

error log::

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "text_classifier.py", line 3, in 
>       import ktrain
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ai\env\lib\site-packages\ktrain__init__.py", line 2, in 
>       from .imports import *
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ai\env\lib\site-packages\ktrain\imports.py", line 209, in 
>       import cchardet as chardet
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ai\env\lib\site-packages\cchardet__init__.py", line 1, in 
>       from cchardet import _cchardet
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working on virtualenv

- I moved to conda env
- pip install ktrain
- pip install tensorflow=2.0
- pip uninstall h5py
- pip install h5py

Now it's working fine, thanks for the idea conda install -c conda-forge cchardet

Answer (score 1):

Try updating cchardet:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cchardet
```

Comment: cchardet: 2.16 i have installed, still  the issue exist