# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'thread' while importing ktrain

Tags: python, installation, pip, ktrain

I am trying to do topic modeling, using `ktrain`.

It gives me a weird error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-ccbda6fc29a3> in <module>
----> 1 import ktrain

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ktrain\__init__.py in <module>
  1 from .version import __version__
----> 2 from . import imports as I
  3 from .core import ArrayLearner, GenLearner, get_predictor, load_predictor, release_gpu_memory
  4 from .vision.learner import ImageClassLearner
  5 from .text.learner import BERTTextClassLearner, TransformerTextClassLearner

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ktrain\imports.py in <module>
227 logging.getLogger("transformers").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
228 try:
--> 229     import transformers
230 except ImportError:
231     warnings.warn("transformers not installed - needed by various models in 'text' module")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py in <module>
 20 # Integrations: this needs to come before other ml imports
 21 # in order to allow any 3rd-party code to initialize properly
---> 22 from .integrations import (  # isort:skip
 23     is_comet_available,
 24     is_optuna_available,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\integrations.py in <module>
 71 
 72 try:
---> 73     import mlflow  # noqa: F401
 74 
 75     _has_mlflow = True

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\__init__.py in <module>
 45 import mlflow.tracking as tracking  # noqa
 46 
---> 47 _configure_mlflow_loggers(root_module_name=__name__)
 48 
 49 if sys.version_info.major == 2:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\logging_utils.py in 
_configure_mlflow_loggers(root_module_name)
 32                 'handlers': ['mlflow_handler'],
 33                 'level': 'INFO',
---> 34                 'propagate': False,
 35             },
 36         },

~\Anaconda3\lib\logging\config.py in dictConfig(config)
797 def dictConfig(config):
798     """Configure logging using a dictionary."""
--> 799     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
800 
801 

~\Anaconda3\lib\logging\config.py in configure(self)
533                 disable_existing = config.pop('disable_existing_loggers', True)
534 
--> 535                 _clearExistingHandlers()
536 
537                 # Do formatters first - they don't refer to anything else

~\Anaconda3\lib\logging\config.py in _clearExistingHandlers()
270     """Clear and close existing handlers"""
271     logging._handlers.clear()
--> 272     logging.shutdown(logging._handlerList[:])
273     del logging._handlerList[:]
274 

~\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in shutdown(handlerList)
2031                 try:
2032                     h.acquire()
-> 2033                     h.flush()
2034                     h.close()
2035                 except (OSError, ValueError):

~\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in flush(self)
1007         try:
1008             if self.stream and hasattr(self.stream, "flush"):
-> 1009                 self.stream.flush()
1010         finally:
1011             self.release()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py in flush(self)
339         send will happen in the background thread
340         """
--> 341         if self.pub_thread.thread.is_alive():
342             # request flush on the background thread
343             self.pub_thread.schedule(self._flush)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'thread'
```

Looks like a common problem, but still cannot fix it.

I tried:

`!pip install ktrain` and `!pip install ktrain --upgrade` in Jupyter

`conda install -c conda-forge cchardet` as [recommended here](https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/issues/138) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784527/ktrain-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

`pip install ktrain` in the command line

Comment: https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/422

Comment: @LiorCohen, thanks, tried this did not help. I tried to downgrade `ipykernel` library.